# Coherence diagrams for monoidal categories which have underlying sets are "automatically" natural?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I am just getting into monoidal categories, and first I am verifying at $FdVect$ is one, the monoidal operation being the usual vector-space tensor product. (Which I also just learned, so I may be getting it wrong here)

I defined the associator $\alpha: (V\otimes W)\otimes Y\rightarrow V\otimes (W\otimes Y)$ the only way I saw, which is
$$(v\otimes w)\otimes y \mapsto v\otimes (w\otimes y)$$

which I assumed without further thought is well-defined isomorphism. Assuming so, it is clearly a natural transformation, as I verified without loss of generality for a quick diagram with respect to $v\in V$.

But in some sense, which intuitively seems to be because its components are set functions with an underlying assignment, this definition seems 'stronger' than an ordinary natural transformation. The pentagon and unit diagrams trivially commute, and it seems that this 'stronger' sense of naturality has the consequence that any diagram that is 'well-defined at the type level' in the sense of being a syntactically correct diagram with respect to the arrows' domains and codomains, in fact commutes trivially. In this case, the 'stronger' naturality extends beyond the naturality of associators/unit arrows, and completes them into 'trivial commuters'.

This intuition is probably naive as I am still a novice, but I was wondering if this is an example of a phenomenon I have not learned about yet. Of course I could also be completely wrong even about the definition I gave above but I haven't seen anything wrong with it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are more or less using the fact that $\text{Set}$ is symmetric monoidal with a very obvious associator, since its symmetric monoidal structure is the categorical product, together with the fact that the free vector space functor $\text{Set} \to \text{Vect}$ is symmetric monoidal. (The relevance of free vector spaces is that tensor products are constructed as quotients of free vector spaces; you're implicitly using that fact when you write down the associator by writing down what it does to pure tensors.)

You might also be interested in the [coherence theorem for monoidal categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherence+theorem+for+monoidal+categories).

Comment: OK, I will investigate this. The coherence theorem seems to state my suspicion about all such diagrams commuting. But the pentagon and unit diagrams are exactly what are required for this proof, though in this case the diagrams happen to not be necessary because of the properties of this special case (as you listed), correct?